# (C++) why static member can be used before it is initialized?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, static-members

I write this test code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date {
    int d;
    int m;
    int y;

public:
    static Date default_date;

public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y) {
        default_date.display();
        this->d = d ? d : default_date.d;
        this->m = m ? m : default_date.m;
        this->y = y ? y : default_date.y;
    }
    void display() { std::cout << d << "-" << m << "-" << y << std::endl; }
};

Date Date::default_date(25, 12, 2018);

int main() {
    Date d = Date(0, 0, 0);
    d.display();
    Date::default_date.display();
}
```

and the output is:

```
0-0-0
25-12-2018
25-12-2018
25-12-2018
```

OK, here is my question.

The static member `default_date` is initialized outside the class definition and using the constructor of class.

However, when the constructor is called, it seems that `default_date` already exists. I even execute `default_date.display()` and get the output `0-0-0`.

Why I can visit `default_date` before it is constructed/initialized?

Comment: [This initialization reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The first time the constructor is called is the point of initialization of `default_date`. And inside this constructor, before the members are assigned their supposed values, the constructor constructor calls `display()`, which prints zero-initialized values of the members.

Comment: Class statics aren't initialised on construction, they are initialised on program start, otherwise classes with statics that aren't ever constructed will never be initialised

Comment: @AlanBirtles see the question to which this one is marked as duplicate: the storage for them is zero-initialized before any other initialization.

Comment: Ah, I see now I misread your answer